# Synonym for "to address the question"

Tags: synonyms

I would like to state the following two sentences:

"The ... problem addresses the question of ..."

"Another direction of research addresses the question of ..."

I would like to replace the second sentence, as it again uses this "to address".

So how about:

"Another direction of research is concerned with the question .."

"Another direction of research asks the question .."

Is there another sentence to avoid "question" completely?

Thank you very much for any inputs.

Comment: It's really not clear how many questions you're actually asking here.  Can you please rewrite this question so it asks **one single question**, and make it more obvious what that question **is**?

Comment: Sorry for that, I tried to make it clearer. Is it clear now?

Comment: Yes, thanks.  You want to avoid repeating yourself too much in the second sentence, right?

Comment: Exactly. The second sentence is like 5 sentences after the first sentence in my text that I am writing. This is why I would like to avoid repetition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Another direction of research invokes answers with ..."

"The ... issue dispatches the query of..."

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It is very helpful to see how one can avoid "question" in this context.

Comment: Please explain your answer in full. How are these sentences good alternatives?

Answer (score 1):

You could just say "is concerned with...".

> The foo-bar problem addresses the question of which spoon to use to eat chicken.  Another direction of research is concerned with which fork one should use to eat bacon.

Comment: Great! This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot for your help. And also thank you for the complete sentence which helped me to see how to use this properly. Really helpful!

Comment: Happy to help...